# On asymptotic of logarithm of modulus of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

**Question:** I need to bound Riemann zeta function on the vertical line $s=1/2+\epsilon+it$ where $0\leq t\leq T+\epsilon$, $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrarily small and $T+\epsilon>3$ is not an ordinate of zero of zeta.

My try:
This [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function#Integral_representations) contains the following integral for $\zeta(s)$ with $s=\sigma+it$ valid for all $s\in \mathbb{C}$:

$$(s-1)\zeta(s) = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{(\frac{1}{2}+ix)^{1-s}}{\cosh^2(\pi x)} dx \tag{1}$$

Denote the following $M=\max_{|z|=\frac{3}{2}}{\left|\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+iTz\right)\right|} $ where $T>3$.

So take $s=\frac{1}{2}+iTz$ so we have $s=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}iT e^{i\theta}=\left(\frac{1-3T\sin \theta}{2}\right)+i\left(\frac{3T\cos \theta}{2}\right)$

Note that $s\neq 1$ since $s=1$ means $z=-\frac{i}{2T}$ so that $|z|=\frac{1}{2T}=\frac{3}{2}$ which gives $T=\frac{1}{3}$ and this contradicts the fact that $T>3$.

By $(1)$ we can write $$|\zeta(s)|\leq  \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\left|(\frac{1}{2}+ix)^{1-s}\right|}{\cosh^2(\pi x)} dx \tag{2}$$
$$\left|\left(\frac{1}{2}+ix\right)^{1-s}\right|=\left|\left(\frac{1}{2}+ix\right)^{1-\sigma-it}\right|=\left|\left(\frac{1}{2}+ix\right)^{1-\sigma}\right|\left|\left(\frac{1}{2}+ix\right)^{-it}\right| $$
$$\Rightarrow  \left|\left(\frac{1}{2}+ix\right)^{1-s}\right|= \left(\frac{1}{4}+x^2\right)^{\frac{1-\sigma}{2}} e^{t\tan^{-1}(2x)}\tag{3}$$
So using $(3)$ in $(2)$ we have  $$|\zeta(s)|\leq  \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{4}+x^2\right)^{\frac{1-\sigma}{2}} e^{t\tan^{-1}(2x)}}{\cosh^2(\pi x)} dx \tag{4}$$
So splitting the integral in RHS of $(4)$ $$\frac{2}{\pi}|\zeta(s)|\leq  \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{4}+x^2\right)^{\frac{1-\sigma}{2}} e^{t\tan^{-1}(2x)}}{\cosh^2(\pi x)} dx+\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{4}+x^2\right)^{\frac{1-\sigma}{2}} e^{t\tan^{-1}(2x)}}{\cosh^2(\pi x)} dx \tag{5}$$
In the second integral of $(5)$, subtitute $x=-y$ so we get $$\frac{2}{\pi}|\zeta(s)|\leq  \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{4}+x^2\right)^{\frac{1-\sigma}{2}} (e^{t\tan^{-1}(2x)}+e^{-t\tan^{-1}(2x)})}{\cosh^2(\pi x)} dx \tag{6}$$
Hence $$\frac{2}{\pi}|\zeta(s)|\leq  \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{4}+x^2\right)^{\frac{1-\sigma}{2}} (\cosh(t\tan^{-1}(2x))}{\cosh^2(\pi x)} dx \tag{7}$$
Now $\sigma=\frac{1-3T\sin \theta}{2}$ and $t=\frac{3T\cos \theta}{2}$

I am struggling to prove the required expression.

Comment: This is a general result that is not hard to prove (logaritmic convexity of maximum modulus on vertical lines and the functional equation say) and is presented in the standard books on zeta like Titchmarsh, Ivic as well as in various books on analytic number theory

Comment: @Conrad Thank you. Please write a short answer. I will be very happy for your help.

Comment: actually, I was wrong since as stated the result is far from true as it is well known that $|\zeta(-T)|$ grows like $c^TT!$ away from even integers so for $z=3i/2$ and $T$ st $(1-3T)/2$ is say an odd integer, $\log |\zeta|$ grows like $aT \log T, a>0$ so far from what you claim; this being said if you restrict only on vertical lines to the right of some fixed $\sigma_0$ it is true that $|\zeta (\sigma+iT)|=O(T^{\mu (\sigma)}), \sigma \ge \sigma_0$ with $\mu(\sigma)=1/2-\sigma$ for $\sigma <0$

Comment: @Conrad So the above claim is false? Are you sure about it?

Comment: The way is stated that allows large negative $T$ as zeta increases very fast on the negative axis away from the trivial zeroes (remember that $(1-s)\zeta$ is an entire exponential function of maximal type so grows like $e^{ct\log t}$ somewhere and that is on the negative axis away from the evens); if you mean to bound zeta on vertical lines is more or less correct as noted

Comment: For example you ask for $|\zeta(z+iT)|, |z|\le 3/2$ then result works

Comment: @Conrad I need to bound Riemann zeta function on the vertical line $s=1/2+\epsilon+it$ where $0\leq t\leq T+\epsilon$. Please help me to do this.

Comment: the result easily follows from the answer below of @Travor

Comment: @Conrad How does the result follow from the answer? How should we define $f(z)=\Re(\zeta(g(z)))$ so that $f(z)$ has zeros on some part of the real axis and we can use Jensen's formula.

Comment: @Conrad In the answer below we have $s=1/2+iT$ but we want $s=1/2+\epsilon+it$ where $0\leq t\leq T$. Please help me.

Comment: why does $s=1/2+\epsilon+it$ make any difference; the same estimate holds since the integral is uniformly bounded for $\Re s >\delta >0$ and the $s$ term outside depends on $t$ not of $\sigma$ as long as $\sigma$ is bounded away from zero (and bounded on the positive axis), so one gets $|\zeta(s)| \le |s|c_{\delta}+2$ for large enough $T$ and any $1>\epsilon >0$

Comment: @Conrad I am sorry, I was unable to convey my question. My question is : if $V$ is a vertical line $1/2+\epsilon\to 1/2+\epsilon+iT$ then I have to prove that $$\Im\left(\int_{1/2+\epsilon}^{1/2+\epsilon+iT}\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}ds\right)=\mathcal{O}(\log T)$$ where $\mathcal{O}$ constants depend on $\epsilon$. Please think about this

Comment: @Conrad For this I have defined the function $f(s)$ as $\Re \zeta(g(s))$ as in the question and then I am trying to use Jensen's formula to find the upper bound on number of zeros of $f(s)$

Comment: this is a different question, not what is asked here; should be asked as a separate question and all answers or comments directed there not here

Comment: @Conrad I am sorry for that. Please guide me regarding this. I was unable to express my question.

Comment: @Conrad I have earlier posted as a different question. Please answer there. See- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4484087/change-in-argument-of-the-riemann-zeta-function-near-the-critical-line

Answer (score 1):

It will be better use another integral representation of $\zeta(s)$:

$$
\zeta(s)={s\over s-1}-s\int_1^\infty{x-\lfloor x\rfloor\over x^{s+1}}\mathrm dx
$$

Set $s=\frac12+iT$, then we have for $T\ge2$ that $|\zeta(s)|=O(T)$. This indicates that $\log|\zeta(s)|<\log T+O(1)$, and your result follows.

Comment: We have $s=\frac{1}{2}+iTz$ where $|z|=3/2$ so we have $s=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}iT e^{i\theta}=\left(\frac{1-3T\sin \theta}{2}\right)+i\left(\frac{3T\cos \theta}{2}\right)$. So $\Re(s)\in \mathbb{R}$, but your integral is defined only for $\Re(s)>0$

Comment: Actually I intend to ask another question. See here and please try to answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4484087/change-in-argument-of-the-riemann-zeta-function-near-the-critical-line